# Getting java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Keys to send should be a not null CharSequence as the stored value returns null Any leads would be helpful

Tags: selenium-webdriver, java

Scenario:
There are 3 fields in the Screen where i enter a number in the 1st field text box
and i need to enter the same number in the 3rd and 4th text box as well

///So in this case i have created methods to store the entered text as seen below:

```
  public  String checkcreatedSampleNoentered() throws InterruptedException {
          Thread.sleep(3500);
          String numberfromsample = "";
          {
          samplenos= "//input[@formcontrolname='sample']";
          Thread.sleep(500);
          WebElement samplenoteno = driver.findElement(By.xpath(samplenos));
              numberfromsample = samplenoteno.getAttribute("value");
              System.out.println("Print the sampenumber:"+numberfromsample);

      }
      return numberfromsample; - this should return the number that was created in the first text box
```

}

```
public String getsampleNo() throws InterruptedException {
    return checkcreatedSampleNoentered();
}
public void storeSampleNo() throws InterruptedException {
    samplenos = checkcreatedSampleNoentered();

}
```

In CommonUseUtils i have created the getters and setters for this:

```
 public class CommonUseUtil {
public static String samplenos;
public static String getSamplenos() {
    return samplenos;
}

public  void setSamplenos(String samplenos) {
    CommonUseUtil.samplenos = samplenos;
}
```

}

And in the method where iam using to call this samplenumber text

```
     apputils.doSendKeys(palletNo,CommonUseUtil.getSamplenos());
```

Basically the samplenumber returns as null so that is why iam getting this error

Any leads would be very helpful

Answer (score -1):

The error "java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Keys to send should be a not null CharSequence as the stored value returns null" is occurring because the value being retrieved by the method `checkcreatedSampleNoentered()` is returning null. This means that the element from which you are trying to get the value is not present or the value is not being stored properly.

Here are a few things you can try:

1 Check if the element locator is correct - Make sure that the locator used to identify the element is correct and is able to identify the element properly.

2 Check if the element is visible and enabled - Make sure that the element is visible and enabled before trying to get the value. You can use explicit waits to ensure that the element is visible and enabled before proceeding.

3 Check if the value is being stored properly - Make sure that the value is being stored properly in the `samplenos` variable. You can print the value of `samplenos` before returning it to ensure that it is not null.

4 Check if the value is being set properly - Make sure that the value of `samplenos` is being set properly in the `CommonUseUtil` class. You can print the value of `samplenos` after setting it to ensure that it is not null.

Here's an updated version of your code with the modifications:

```
public String checkcreatedSampleNoentered() throws InterruptedException {
    Thread.sleep(3500);
    String numberfromsample = "";
    samplenos= "//input[@formcontrolname='sample']";
    WebElement samplenoteno = new WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.xpath(samplenos)));
    if(samplenoteno.isEnabled()){
        numberfromsample = samplenoteno.getAttribute("value");
        System.out.println("Print the sampenumber:"+numberfromsample);
    }
    return numberfromsample;
}

public String getsampleNo() throws InterruptedException {
    return checkcreatedSampleNoentered();
}

public void storeSampleNo() throws InterruptedException {
    CommonUseUtil.setSamplenos(checkcreatedSampleNoentered());
}
```

In the `checkcreatedSampleNoentered()` method, I've added explicit wait for the element to be visible and enabled before getting the value. In the `storeSampleNo()` method, I'm setting the value of samplenos in the `CommonUseUtil` class using the `setSamplenos()` method. You can now call `storeSampleNo()` method to store the value of the first field and then use `getSamplenos()` method to retrieve the stored value for the third and fourth fields.

I hope this helps you in resolving the issue.

---

**Edit:**

If the value is being printed correctly in the checkcreatedSampleNoentered() method, but not being retrieved properly from the CommonUseUtil class, it's possible that the issue is with the scope of the samplenos variable.

In the CommonUseUtil class, the samplenos variable is declared as a static variable. This means that the value of the variable will be shared across all instances of the class. However, in the checkcreatedSampleNoentered() method, the value of samplenos is set for the current instance of the class, and not for the static variable.

To fix this issue, you can change the samplenos variable in the CommonUseUtil class from static to instance variable. Then, you can create an instance of the CommonUseUtil class in your main class and use it to set and get the value of samplenos.

Here's an updated version of your code with the modifications:

```
public class CommonUseUtil {
public String samplenos;
public String getSamplenos() {
return samplenos;
}
public void setSamplenos(String samplenos) {
this.samplenos = samplenos;
}
}

public String checkcreatedSampleNoentered() throws InterruptedException {
Thread.sleep(3500);
String numberfromsample = "";
samplenos= "//input[@formcontrolname='sample']";
WebElement samplenoteno = new WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.xpath(samplenos)));
if(samplenoteno.isEnabled()){
numberfromsample = samplenoteno.getAttribute("value");
System.out.println("Print the sampenumber:"+numberfromsample);
}
return numberfromsample;
}

public String getsampleNo() throws InterruptedException {
return checkcreatedSampleNoentered();
}

public void storeSampleNo() throws InterruptedException {
CommonUseUtil commonUseUtil = new CommonUseUtil();
commonUseUtil.setSamplenos(checkcreatedSampleNoentered());
}
```

Now, you can create an instance of the CommonUseUtil class in your main class and use it to set and get the value of samplenos. For example:

```
CommonUseUtil commonUseUtil = new CommonUseUtil();
commonUseUtil.storeSampleNo();
System.out.println("Print the sampleno:" + commonUseUtil.getSamplenos());
```

I hope this helps you in resolving the issue.

Comment: tried as per what you said but still getting null value ...element locator is getting highlighted ..  System.out.println("Print the sampleno:" + CommonUseUtil.getSamplenos()); this part is returning null ...@IAmMilinPatel any other inputs?

Comment: Did a sysout in the checkcreatedSampleNoentered method and it is printing the number the issue is in commonuseutil..bz when i try to Commonuseutil.getsampleno it is not printing the number - @IAmMilinPatel

Comment: Have tried to add more information based on your comments.